# In Vue, how do I store my dada in a session so I can access it in any page?

Tags: html, vue.js, session

How do I store my dada in a session so I can access it in any page? And only destroy the data whenever the page is closed.

Vue.js:

```
new Vue({
el: '#item-data',
data () {
  return {
    data:[],
    selectedUser:'',
    itemCart: [],
    quantity: ''
  }
},
mounted () {
  **** API CALL ****
    }
  })
    .then((response) => {
      // handle success
      this.data = response.data.items
      removeLoader();
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      // handle error
      console.log(error);
    })
    .then(function () {
      // always executed
    });
},
methods:{
  sendInfo(items) {
    this.selectedUser = items;
  },
  addCart: function(cartdets){
    this.itemCart.push({cartdets});
    console.log(cartdets);
  }
}
```

})

The data i want to store into a session is itemCart[].

Comment: Session is a bit of a loaded term. It can mean different things to different systems. But what I think you are looking for is either in vuex (https://vuex.vuejs.org/) or in localStorage (https://javascript.info/localstorage)

Comment: Oh, thank you! Ill check vuex. Can i use it on an html project?

Comment: vuex might be an option